Firebase bug: FIRInvalidArgumentException - Document path cannot be empty
I use the same code from another project. It works there, but doesn't work in the 2nd project.
A crash happens when I check the blacklist collection, but the same code works for another project with the same collection.
crash happens because of this (again it's same code):
.onAppear() {
    checkIfBlacklisted()
}

func checkIfBlacklisted() {

    guard let deviceId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "deviceID") else {
        print("Device ID not found in UserDefaults")
        return
    }

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let blacklistRef = db.collection("blacklist").document(deviceId)

    blacklistRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error checking blacklist status: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if let document = document, document.exists {
            print("Device is blacklisted.")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "blacklisted")
            // Handle the case where the device is blacklisted, e.g., show an alert or restrict access.
        } else {
            print("Device is not blacklisted.")
            // Proceed with the app’s normal flow.
        }
    }
}

Fatal Exception: FIRInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x83f20 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x172b8 objc_exception_throw
2  Rayo                           0x2ae12c firebase::firestore::util::ObjcThrowHandler(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
3  Rayo                           0x2adc28 firebase::firestore::util::Throw(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)
4  Rayo                           0x2b35ec void firebase::firestore::util::ThrowInvalidArgument<>(char const*)
5  Rayo                           0x2b8e90 -[FIRCollectionReference documentWithPath:]
6  Rayo                           0x24dd8 specialized LogicView.checkIfBlacklisted() + 56 (LogicView.swift:56)
7  SwiftUI                        0x26ef68 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
8  SwiftUI                        0x26757c -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
9  SwiftUI                        0x266c54 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
10 SwiftUI                        0x2656e0 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
11 SwiftUI                        0x263e10 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
12 SwiftUI                        0x263ba0 -[UIScrollView(SwiftUI) _swiftui_adjustsContentInsetWhenScrollDisabled]
13 SwiftUI                        0x178d00 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1130
14 UIKitCore                      0x10918 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
15 QuartzCore                     0x7f26c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
16 QuartzCore                     0x7edf0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
17 QuartzCore                     0xd9fd8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
18 QuartzCore                     0x4eee0 CA::Transaction::commit()
19 UIKitCore                      0x1c55bc __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2
20 CoreFoundation                 0x65c9c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
21 CoreFoundation                 0x53dec __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
22 CoreFoundation                 0x53498 __CFRunLoopRun
23 CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
24 GraphicsServices               0x11a8 GSEventRunModal
25 UIKitCore                      0x40aae8 -[UIApplication _run]
26 UIKitCore                      0x4bed98 UIApplicationMain
27 SwiftUI                        0x3f4294 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283
28 SwiftUI                        0x3a0860 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283
29 SwiftUI                        0x3ac61c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_283
30 Rayo                           0x2d8cc main (AccentAI_IOSApp.swift)
31 ???                            0x1b3b13154 (Missing)


To troubleshoot: log the deviceId and check what value it, or put a breakpoint on the line that initializes blacklistRef (assuming that is the LogicView.checkIfBlacklisted() + 56  from the stack trace) and check the value of deviceId in the debugger.

Just because deviceId isn't nil doesn't mean it isn't an empty string
